# Can not figure out why card game subtracts cards wonky

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a card game called beggar my neighbor, where a deck of cards is created and then randomly sorted and evenly divided to 2 players. Then, each player draws cards and places it on the table until a penalty card is played (face cards). Each face card has a debt value of 1-4, where the other player has to play that number of cards to the table. However, the other player could draw a penalty card themselves, restarting the debt payment. If a player plays a debt and the other player plays all cards and not any debts, they player who played the debt, takes all of the cards on the table. The winner is the player who has all of the cards of the deck.

My problem is that when the game runs by itself (play() in the console), the stack (# of cards each player has), decreases not by 1, but by some arbitrary amount. How would I fix this?

EDIT:

```
if(G['debt']>0):
            # Paying a debt.
            print("Turn {}: Player {} is paying a debt.".format(turn, current(G)))
            # May want to show debt cards being played with displayCard().
            # Careful to handle any penalty cards paid as part of a debt!
            if len(G['stacks'][G['next']]) > G['debt']:
                #if 
                for i in range(G['debt']):
                    # Print what card is being played
                    print("Turn {}: Player {} Played {}".format(turn, current(G), (displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))))
                    # Test if card being played is a penalty card
                    if G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]  == 1:
                        #G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                        G['debt']=4
                        i=0
                    elif G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0] == 13:
                        #G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                        G['debt']=3
                        i=0
                    elif G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]  == 12:
                        #G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                        G['debt']=2
                        i=0
                    elif G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]  == 11:
                        #G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                        G['debt']=1
                        i=0
                # Add the card to the table
                G['table'].append(G['stacks'][G['next']][0])
                # Remove the card from the player's stack
                G['stacks'][G['next']].pop()
            else:
                G['debt'] = 0
```

original code:

```
from random import randint

def createDeck(N=13, S=('spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds')):
    return([(v, s) for v in range(1,N+1) for s in S])

def displayCard(c):
    suits = {'spades':'\u2660', 'hearts':'\u2661', 'diamonds':'\u2662', 'clubs':'\u2663'}
    return(''.join( [ str(c[0]), suits[c[1]] ] ))

def simpleShuffle(D):
    for i in range(len(D)):
        r=randint(i,len(D)-1)
        D[i],D[r]=D[r],D[i]
    return(D)

def newGame(N=13, S=('spades', 'hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds')):
    d = simpleShuffle(createDeck(N,S))
    return {'table':[], 'next':0, 'debt':0, 'stacks':[d[:len(d)//2],d[len(d)//2:]]}

def describeGame(G):
    return('Player:'+str(G['next'])+' Stacks:['+str(len(G['stacks'][0]))+', '+str(len(G['stacks'][1]))+'] Table:'+str(len(G['table']))+' Debt:'+str(G['debt']))

def current(G):
    return(G['next'])

def opponent(G):
    if G['next']==0:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)

def advancePlayer(G):
    G['next']=opponent(G)
    return(G)

def play(G=newGame()):
    turn = 0

    while(G['stacks'][0]!=0 and G['stacks'][1]!=0): 
        # Show the state of play.
        print("Turn {}: {}".format(turn, describeGame(G)))

        # Make a move. First, check to see if a debt is due. If so,
        # pay it.
        if(G['debt']>0):
            # Paying a debt.
            print("Turn {}: Player {} is paying a debt.".format(turn, current(G)))

            if len(G['stacks'][G['next']]) >= G['debt']:
                for i in range(G['debt']):
                    # Print what card is being played
                    print("Turn {}: Player {} Played {}".format(turn, current(G), (displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))))
                    # Test if card being played is a penalty card
                    if G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 1:
                        G['debt']=4
                        i=0
                    elif G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 13:
                        G['debt']=3
                        i=0
                    elif G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 12:
                        G['debt']=2
                        i=0
                    elif G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 11:
                        G['debt']=1
                        i=0
                # Add the card to the table
                G['table'].append(G['stacks'][G['next']][0])
                # Remove the card from the player's stack
                G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                # Increment turn
                turn = turn + 1

        else:
            print("Turn {}: Player {} Played {}".format(turn, current(G), (displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))))
            #print(displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))

            # Check if c is a penalty card.
            if(G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==1 or G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==11 or G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==12 or G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==13):
                  # Set up a new debt for the other player and advance
                  # immediately to next turn.
                  if (G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 1:
                      G['debt']=4 
                  elif (G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 13:
                      G['debt']=3 
                  elif (G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 12:
                      G['debt']=2 
                  else:
                      G['debt']=1 

            # Not a penalty card; add it to the table.
            G['table'].append(G['stacks'][G['next']][0])
            # Remove the card 
            G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)

        # Advance to next player.
        advancePlayer(G)
        # Increment turn counter.
        turn = turn + 1

    # Exit loop: indicate winner.`enter code here`
    print("Player {} wins in {} turns.".format(opponent(G), turn))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stopped bugging for me and the rounds are counted accordingly.

```
def play(G=newGame()):
turn = 0

while(len(G['stacks'][0])!=0 and len(G['stacks'][1])!=0):
    # Show the state of play.
    print("Turn {}: {}".format(turn, describeGame(G)))

    # Make a move. First, check to see if a debt is due. If so,
    # pay it.
    if(G['debt']>0):
        # Paying a debt.
        print("Turn {}: Player {} is paying a debt.".format(turn, current(G)))
        if len(G['stacks'][G['next']]) >= G['debt']:
            for i in range(G['debt']):
                # Print what card is being played
                print("Turn {}: Player {} Played {} for their debt.".format(turn, current(G), (displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))))
                nextcard = G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]
                # Test if card being played is a penalty card
                if nextcard == 1:
                    G['debt']= 4
                elif nextcard == 13:
                    G['debt']= 3
                elif nextcard == 12:
                    G['debt']= 2
                elif nextcard == 11:
                    G['debt']= 1
                #G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                # Add the card to the table
                G['table'].append(G['stacks'][G['next']][0])
                # Remove the card from the player's stack
                G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)
                # Increment turn
                turn = turn + 1
            # in each iteration the turn is increased
            # however, outside of this loop the turn is increased once again
            # take this into account and remove one turn
            turn -= 1
        else:
            # player has less cards than they have to pay
            # plays all his cards
            print("Turn {}: Player {} has not enough cards to pay their debt.".format(turn, current(G)))
            G['debt'] = 0
            continue
    else:
        print("Turn {}: Player {} Played {}".format(turn, current(G), (displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))))
        #print(displayCard(G['stacks'][G['next']][0]))

        # Check if c is a penalty card.
        if(G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==1 or G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==11 or G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==12 or G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]==13):
              # Set up a new debt for the other player and advance
              # immediately to next turn.
              if (G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 1:
                  G['debt']=4
              elif (G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 13:
                  G['debt']=3
              elif (G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 12:
                  G['debt']=2
              else:
                  G['debt']=1

        # Not a penalty card; add it to the table.
        G['table'].append(G['stacks'][G['next']][0])
        # Remove the card
        G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0)

    # Advance to next player.
    advancePlayer(G)
    # Increment turn counter.
    turn = turn + 1
# Exit loop: indicate winner.`enter code here`
print("Player {} wins in {} turns.".format(opponent(G), turn))
```

The first thing I did was to change the while conditions to `len()` instead of just the stacks.
I also introduced a variable, nextcard:

```
nextcard = G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0]
```

I implemented the else condition that you mentioned (set the debt to 0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I was able to add 
        if len(G['stacks'][G['next']]) == 0:
            break                    To before the if statement to add the card to the table as a special exception to prevent the out of index that would appear every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within this code:

```
if G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 1:
    G['debt']=4
    i=0
elif G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 13:
    G['debt']=3
    i=0
elif G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 12:
    G['debt']=2
    i=0
elif G['stacks'][G['next']].pop(0) == 11:
    G['debt']=1
    i=0
```

When a card is popped, it is removed from the stack. This is done everytime the "check" is performed. Thus, the arbitrary numbers come from when the check returns true. If it is eg. 13, it will remove 2 cards, for the value 12 it will remove 3 cards, etc.

Instead of popping the card, you should check it, like you do later:

```
if G['stacks'][G['next']][0][0])== 1:
```

Comment: When I did that, the stack does decrease by 1. However, the same card is played x amount (number of debt) times.

Comment: I edited my answer: after the check returns true, you would have to pop the card! Sorry, I didn't think of this.

Comment: Firstly, when I run the program it does not end, Second, it only removes 1 card from the players stack, and does not remove the top 4 cards from the deck, thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Hey I was playing around with the code a little and I found a case that you did not describe (a possible reason why the game is not stopping if the case occurs): What if a player has less cards than he has to pay as debt:             if len(G['stacks'][G['next']]) >= G['debt']: .... <- there is no else described.
How would you like your game to react?

Comment: I added a else to set the debt to 0 when the cards are < the debt amount. When I run my code, the player who is playing the debt keeps playing the exact same card, and each time I run the program, the game is over in exactly 52 turns.

Comment: Can you update your code so I can take a closer look?